# Can we get a patent for set of mathematical instructions of similar types

Tags: patentability, patent-applications, theorem

Can we get the patent on set of equation discoveries between the properties of a set of numbers that can be applied for any two numbers of that set..

for e.g. multi relational equations between two odd numbers,consecutive numbers,etc..

Comment: for E.g. Different theories for cons.odd numbers.All are true between any two cons.odd numbers..

Comment: US, EU, both, others?

Answer (score 2):

No.

What you are describing is pure mathematics without any particular implementation. Every state (as far as I know) disallows patents for pure mathematics.

For example, such an invention:

- would not comply with 35 USC §101 in the US, since unapplied mathematics is probably the only area which everyone agrees is an abstract invention without anything more;
- would not comply with Art 52(a) EPC at the EPO, which explicitly excludes mathematical methods; and
- would not comply with PCT rule 39.1(i) in the international phase, which provides that mathematical theories may not be searched.

Answer (score 0):

Maca's answer is excellent and all I have to add is that "laws of nature" are specifically excluded.

Here are some links:

http://www.bilskiblog.com/blog/laws-of-nature/

https://ilr.law.uiowa.edu/print/volume-99-issue-3/the-natural-complexity-of-patent-eligibility/

http://www.abajournal.com/magazine/article/new_laws_of_nature_law_ruling_questions_scientific_patents/

But the above links are older, and refer to previous cases. I suspect you'll want to look at CRISPR, for more recent developments:

https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/speaking-of-science/wp/2017/02/15/broad-institute-scientist-prevails-in-epic-patent-fight-over-crispr/?utm_term=.4602c683a8b7

It's *possible* if you narrow your claims to a concrete application of the algorithm, there may be some wiggle room, but you'll need to consult with an experience patent attorney.

*As Maca notes, what you describe is ineligible because "it is pure mathematics without any particular implementation."*

**Certainly don't disclose until you've determined there is no strategy that may produce a viable patent application.**  (This always carries the caveat that, in this particular area, the only certainty is uncertainty.  Patenting can be an expensive process, and there are no guarantees of a grant.  Eligibility, particularly in regard to algorithms, has narrowed significantly "[post-Alice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International)".)

Also might be worth checking out Gene Quinn's [A Software Patent History: The Algorithm Cases](http://www.ipwatchdog.com/2015/01/01/a-software-patent-history-the-algorithm-cases/id=52935/).